# How to transfer email accounts and email messages from cPanel to Plesk 12?

Tags: email, backup, cpanel, plesk

I was using shared hosting with cPanel. Now I have bought dedicated server and Plesk web pro edition included with it free. Now **I want to transfer my cPanel email accounts to Plesk panel**. How can I do it?

> Note: I don't have root access or SSH account on shared hosting.

According to this [topic](http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115612) I may have root access to cPanel of old server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to ask free migration assistance here https://sp.parallels.com/products/plesk/how-to-migrate/